# Why do we need to use `avr-objcopy` after `avr-as`?

Tags: avr, assembly

New to assembly, I'm surprised to see that we need to use `avr-objcopy` after invoking `avr-as`, in order to obtain an Intel Hex file, so where does this come from ?

Comment: Posting the full commands including flags might help. Are you using avr-objcopy to create an Intel Hex file from the executable, for download?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `*-as` is the GNU Assembler utility, used to produce binary object files `*.o`. This format is incompatible with the Intel Hex format, which is basically plain text file, containing the binary data encoded with its textual representation. `objcopy` is capable of extracting the binary information in one format and translating it to another. And it is what it does.